# Parsing process command-line arguments from pargs in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, options

I get list of PIDs in my bash scripts (Java processes) and have to analyze their command-line arguments to determine which instance of server each PID corresponds to.

At the moment I do it that way using sed/cut:

```
  PARGS=$(pargs -l $PID)
  PARGS_ARR=($PARGS)
  NODE='UNKNOWN'
  for ARG in ${PARGS_ARR[@]}
  do
    # trim single quotes 
    ARG=$(echo $ARG | sed "s/'//g")

    # split by equals sign
    ARGL=$(echo $ARG | cut -f1 -d=)
    ARGR=$(echo $ARG | cut -f2 -d=)

    if [ "$ARGL" == "-DnodeId" ]; then
      NODE=$ARGR
    fi
  done
```

But it works EXTREMELLY SLOW due to large number of command-line parameters (about 20-30 per each PID).

Is there a way to somehow parse command-line parameters and get key=>value parse with a single command?

Answer (score 1):

What does the output of `pargs -l $PID` look like? From your code, it seems like it is a single line containing all the command-line arguments in a format eg:

```
arg1=val1 arg2=val2
```

If so, you can collect the value for the `-DnodeId` argument with a `sed` command:

```
$ ARGS="-DfirstArg=foo -DanotherArg=bar -DnodeId=1234 -DlastArg=baz"
$ echo "$ARGS" | sed -r 's/.*-DnodeId=([^ ]+).*/\1/g'
1234
```

So your script could become:

```
PARGS=$(pargs -l $PID)
NODE='UNKNOWN'
if [ -n "$(grep "DnodeId" <(echo "$PARGS"))" ]; then
    NODE=$(echo "$PARGS" | sed -r 's/.*-DnodeId=([^ ]+).*/\1/g')
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is what comes to the right of `=` if what's on the left is `-DnodeId`, you can do this:

```
NODE=$(pargs -l $PID| awk -F '-DnodeId=' '{sub(" .*","",$2);print $2}')
```

This will print whatever comes to the right of the pattern `-DnodeId=` up to but excluding the first space. If there's more than one `-DnodeId` on the command line, it will work with the first one only.

To handle more than one `-DnodeId` per line is also possible:

```
NODES=($(pargs -l $PID| awk -F '-DnodeId=' '{
          for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
              sub(" .*","",$i);
              print $i
          }
        }'
))
```

Comment: Returns:

awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Can't rigure out why.

Comment: @user1065145 What OS is this? This works fine on my `(g)awk` 4.0.1 running on Debian.

Comment: That worked, but with nawk! THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: @user1065145 This is strange. As far as I know, this solution uses only POSIX constructs.

Comment: @JosephR. But... POSIX arrays?

Comment: @mikeserv Good point. The error was due to the first solution, however.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you're doing would definitely be very slow as every time you *`var=$(command substitute)`* you must stop and wait for its output before you move to the next step. I'm willing to bet you'd wait a lot less if you just processed it in stream with *`sed,`* the *`stream editor:`*

```
NODE="$(pargs -l $PID | sed -rn '/(-DnodeId)=(\S*)/{s//\2/pq}')"
```

I'm not totally sure about the single quotes - I just typed this on my phone - but *`sed's y`* function can certainly handle it if you still need it.

Above Josh demonstrates a fail case. Probably it would be much simpler just to add:

```
${NODE:?PID not found...quitting}
```

After running the above *`sed`* command.

It occurs to me these are not necessarily already separated by line, we can handle that easily enough with 1 more *`|pipe`* - still all in one data stream, while also accounting for the possibility of multiple matches:

```
. <<PIDSED /dev/stdin
    $(pargs -l $PID |\
        sed -rn 's/(-DnodeId)=(\S*)/\
            echo "NODE$((i=i+1))=\2" ;/gp' |\
        . /dev/stdin)
PIDSED
```

Answer (score 1):

Process the arguments using `bash`, not external processes

```
for ARG in "${PARGS_ARR[@]}"
do
  # trim single quotes 
  ARG=${ARG//\'}

  # split by equals sign
  IFS="=" read ARGL ARGR <<< "$ARG"

  if [[ "$ARGL" == "-DnodeId" ]]; then
    NODE=$ARGR
  fi
done
```